# Query slow in Web App, but fast in command line

Tags: sql, sqlite, inner-join

I am need to retrieve records from two tables which are linked by a third. Session content doesn't contain any information I need besides the keys to link the other two tables.

I am currently using these joins:

```
SELECT sessions.name, rooms.name, slots.type, slots.dayString, slots.startHour, slots.startMinute, slots.endHour, slots.endMinute
FROM slots
INNER JOIN sessions
INNER JOIN rooms
;
```

It only takes 50 ms in SQLite DB browser, but takes multiple seconds of buffering when I call the related API endpoint.

I can't use it if it takes this long to load Is there anyway to improve query time besides limiting the number of rows it returns (currently returns 77000)?

Comment: can you elaborate what are the join conditions (amongst slots, sessions and rooms) ?

Comment: @KenLee what do you mean by 'join conditions'? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Session content doesn't contain any information I need besides the
> keys to link the other two tables.

But you don't use these keys to set the conditions to link the tables, so what you are actually doing is a `CROSS` join of the 3 tables and the result is the Cartesian product of all the rows of all the tables.
Use an `ON` clause for each join to set the conditions:

```
SELECT sn.name, r.name, s.type, s.dayString, s.startHour, s.startMinute, s.endHour, s.endMinute
FROM slots s 
INNER JOIN sessions sn ON sn.slot_id = s.slot_id
INNER JOIN rooms r ON r.room_id = sn.room_id;
```

Change the column names I used in the `ON` clauses to the actual ones.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I replace all the column names, but what is the "s" after "FROM slots" for? It works when I remove the s, but I am not sure if it represents anything important.

Comment: @WhynarySearch `s` is defined in `FROM slots s` and it is the alias of the table `slots`. It is used, just like the other 2 aliases `sn` and `r` to qualify the column names, so there is no ambiguity when referring to a column like `slot_id` which exists in both tables `slots` and `sessions`. The code should work as it is without removing these aliases.

Comment: @WhynarySearch as you can see here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=703130647ceb4e7fb12fe67f3306b674 the code is syntactically correct, provided the column names are correct.

Comment: My mistake. Is this  ```INNER JOIN sessions sn ON sn.slot_id = s.slot_id``` Superiour to this ```INNER JOIN sessions ON sessions.slot_Id = slots.slot_Id ```. How do they differ?

Comment: @WhynarySearch No, they work they same. I prefer to use aliases like `t` or `s` which make the code shorter (and I believe more readable). Also, when there is a self join of a table, then it's not possible to do something like: `FROM tablename INNER JOIN tablename ON tablename.col = tablename.col` but this would work: `FROM tablename t1 INNER JOIN tablename t2 ON t1.col = t2.col`.